# Problem with setcookie in PHP

Tags: php, setcookie

```
if( isset($_COOKIE["cl1"] ) )
{
    echo $_COOKIE["cl1"];
}
else
{
    setcookie("cl1","me",time()+ 3600);
}

if( isset($_COOKIE["cl1"] ) )
{
    echo "the cookie is set";
}
```

When I run this page the page must show "the cookie is set" but the screen is empty. Why?

Comment: why would it say that when you are setting a cookie called cl1 but checking for a cookie called user?

Comment: you've changed your code.  is this the final version?  confusing...

Answer (score 0):

The cookie will not be available until the next page load. The cookie is sent with the page request. A hack to make it so that cookie value will be in the $_COOKIE array on the same page load would be:

```
setcookie("cl1","me",time()+ 3600);
$_COOKIE['cl1'] = "me";
```

Comment: i test it in another page but has same output.

Comment: I just tried your code and I see no issue with it. If you print_r() your $_COOKIE superglobal does it have anything in it? Do you have cookies disabled in your browser?

Comment: When I run your code verbatim I get the following output: methe cookie is seted

Comment: thanks it worked but now problem is that when i try in another page use from this cookie with **if(isset(cookie['cl1']){ echo "hi";  }** it doesn't worked why?

Comment: Because you need to call it as $_COOKIE['cl1'] not cookie['c1']

Comment: i eddited that but there was same problem